# switch view controller has a black screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I write code in IB action to check condition to switch view controller in same story board but if I touch button it go to black screen

this is my code

```
-(IBAction)Buyvoyage{
if (ck==1) {
    NSLog(@"brought IAP");
    VoyageplayViewController *voy = [[VoyageplayViewController alloc]init];
        [self presentViewController:voy animated:YES completion:NULL];        
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
try replacing  
 [self presentViewController:voy animated:YES completion:NULL];  
with  
** [self presentViewController:voy animated:YES completion:nil];**
```

---

```
However, i would prefer you to use seuge by following below steps.  

 1. Create segue from each UIButton to the corresponding UIViewControllers, set Segue identifier in IB by selecting the segue(s) you just created e.g. if you have 2 button then set identifier of the Segue "TestSegue1" and "TestSegue2" respectively.  
 2. Now create an IBaction for UIButton from which you want to navigate, and put below code in that IBAction
 3. Remember to set Tag property in IB of all the UIButton(s) you want to perform navigation on as per your requirement     

// When any of my buttons is pressed, push the next UIViewController using performSeugeWithIdentifier method

- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(UIButton*)sender
{  
    if (sender.tag==1) {  
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"TestSegue1" sender:sender];  
    }
    else if(sender.tag==2) 
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"TestSegue2" sender:sender];
}
```

---

```
Or Use storyboard identifier to present your viewcontroller using below code  

- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(UIButton*)sender
{     
    //Get StoryBoard Identifier using
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [self storyboard]; 
    if(ck==1) {
        VoyageplayViewController *voyVC = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Voyage"];
        [voyVC setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationFullScreen];
        [self presentModalViewController:voyVC  animated:YES];
    }
}
```

**don't forget to set ViewController StoryBoard Id in StoryBoard -> identity inspector**

Comment: I edit NULL to nil but it Black screen again. I use variable name "ck" to check who's buy in app purchase to access  VoyageplayViewController

Comment: Does, "Brought IAPP" been logged into console?

Comment: `if (ck==1) {`
          `NSLog(@"brought IAP");`
         ` VoyageplayViewController *voy = [[VoyageplayViewController alloc]init];`
       `voy.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;`
           ` [self presentViewController:voy animated:YES completion:nil];`
          ` [voy release];}`

Comment: don't forget to set ViewController StoryBoard Id in StoryBoard -> identity inspector

Comment: When using storyboard viewcontroller identifiers then you dont have to alloc/init UIViewController

Comment: set VoyageplayViewController indentitty in storyboard id right? and change to UIViewController *con =[[UIViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"Voyage" bundle:nil]; [self presentViewController:con animated:YES completion:nil];(I set storyboard id name Voyage)

Comment: u hav to set uiviewcontroller identifier. select uiviewcontroller and then select identity inspector and set its identifier there.

Comment: I add "Voyage" in storyboard id in my view controller and edit code to VoyageplayViewController *voy = [[VoyageplayViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"Voyage" bundle:nil]; but it Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle </Users/Cpoint/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/85257E20-5BA3-4CA7-BECB-DDF3F4E77B52/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/4BE48453-7AD7-41CB-8BE8-EEE0A8D5D090/myapp.app> (loaded)' with name 'Voyage''

Comment: It works Thanks Sorry, I don't seen your edit answer.